# How do I pass a string variable with apostrophe (') in a Xpath for Python-Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a web table where I need to `click` the edit template icon (the one that looks like a notepad in the image below) for each row. The table looks like this.

[image]

My code checks for the text and then clicks the icon. I don't have any trouble with the first two but the last one gives an error of invalid xpath expression because of the apostrophe. Below is the code that I am using. The list 'form_titles' is created dynamically by detecting the `.xsn` files that I need to upload from my local folder to each of these forms one by one. Each 'form title' has its own unique `.xsn` file and I use a spreadsheet containing a pre-compiled list for referring each `.xsn` file to its 'form title'.

```
form_titles = ["3.08 Incident Estimates", "3.09 Quotation by the Consultant", "3.10 Employer's Assessment"]

for form in form_titles:    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(),'%s')]" % (form))))
    finally:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),'%s')]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@onclick, 'editProjectFormType')]" % (form)).click()
        time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\` to escape `""` char as below :-

```
form_titles = ["3.08 Incident Estimates", "3.09 Quotation by the Consultant", "3.10 Employer's Assessment"]

for form in form_titles:    
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(),\"%s\")]" % (form))))
    finally:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(),\"%s\")]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@onclick, 'editProjectFormType')]" % (form)).click()
        time.sleep(30)
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Works smooth. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `"%s"` won't work because for some reason, it doesn't remain a string anymore when I do that.

Comment: @Chandral ok thanks, and glad to help you.. I removed it from the answer..although I'm not python guy so I haven't idea why second option not work...:)